# convert p7b to pfx for Azure

Tags: http, ssl, azure, certificate, cloud

I am trying to setup endpoints for Azure.

I was given an .p7b file but I need a .pfx file with private key for Azure.

Is there a way to convert my .p7b to .pfx?

Comment: You covered the same ground in your earlier question [Azure https with pfx file.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699415/azure-https-with-pfx-file). The answer is not going to change just because you ask the question in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Ok, **here is a rundown on the whole Azure SSL certificate rigmarole.**  I've done this with GoDaddy (and more than a bit of help from one of their knowledgeable tech support guys).  Also note that I've done this on Windows 8 Pro; your experience might be slightly different and/or your mileage may vary ;-)

Pay your money to a CA (Certificate Authority) to buy an SSL certificate.

**Create CSR (Certificate Signing Request)**

Now you need to create a CSR , which is text that you must supply to the CA in order for them to create your certificate.  The CSR contains a couple of pieces of information:

1. The name of the domain associated with the certificate.
2. A public key to associate with the certificate.  Note that the CSR that you give to the CA does NOT contain the associated private key.

You create the CSR locally on your PC using IIS Manager.  Note: IIS is included with Windows, but is not installed by default.  [I'll leave the details of installing IIS as an exercise for the student.  Maybe some kind person will edit this answer and fill in those details.]

**EDIT:** rather than installing IIS on your local machine, you can RDP into the cloud service in Azure (very easy to do) and use IIS on that machine to create the CSR and Complete the Signing Request.  If you do this, be sure to do this entire process in one sitting.  If you generate the CSR and then wait to complete the request till sometime later, the cloud service may not be on the same machine and you won't have the "Export" option in IIS.

To create a CSR:

1. Run IIS Manager
2. Select (double-click) Server Certificates
3. In the Actions pane on the right side of the window, click on Create Certificate Request. Common Name is the domain name associated with the certificate. The rest of the fields identify your company.
4. IIS Manager will ask for the Cryptographic Service Provider and Bit Length.  You must select at least a bit length of at least 2048.
5. IIS Manager will create a public/private key pair.  The public key is included in the CSR text file that IIS Manager creates for you.  The private key is stashed away somewhere on your PC (I assume in the personal key store).

To create CSR - you can also refer the detailed steps at [godaddy site](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4800/generating-a-certificate-signing-request-csr-microsoft-iis7?pc_split_value=3). quite helpful.

Now, go back to your CA's website and find the online tool that lets you create the certificate that you purchased.  The first thing it will want you to do is to paste (or upload) the CSR text.  After you jump through your CA's hoops, you will receive one or more certificate files back from them.

**Install certificate files into IIS**

GoDaddy gives you two files: a p7b file and a crt file.

**The crt file** contains your public certificate.  But you can't (yet) upload it to your web hosting provider because it doesn't include the associated private key.  The web host needs the private key as well as the public key because it will be doing end-to-end encryption on your behalf.

**The p7b file** contains the certificates that comprise the "certificate chain" that allows your certificate to be verified up to your CA.  In other words, when someone comes to your website and gets your certificate that claims that your website is run by Acme.com, this certificate chain lets that person's browser verify that your CA vouches for your identity. We'll get back to this file later...

Now you need to combine your public certificate with your private key and store the result in a password-protected pfk file.

Get back into IIS Manager on the same machine that created the CSR, navigate back to the Server Certificates page, and click on Complete Certificate Request (in the Actions pane on the right side of the screen).

1. Tell the wizard to use the certificate file that you received from your CA (in my case it was a crt file, but it might be a different file type if your CA used a different encoding method).
2. Friendly Name should probably be your domain name, but you can also add "SSL" in as well to help distinguish it (e.g. ContosoSSL)
3. Tell the wizard to store the key in your Personal store

To install the certificates into IIS, these detailed steps from [godaddy site help](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4801/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-microsoft-iis-7) may be helpful.

**Get the pfx file**

You should now see your new certificate listed on the Server Certificates page in IIS Manager.  Select that certificate and export it as a pfx file (via the Actions pane on the right side of the screen).

Now you can go to https://manage.windowsazure.com (the Windows Azure management portal), select your website or cloud service, and upload the pfx file to the Azure certificate store.

Whew.  Good luck...

**EDIT**

The above instructions only deal with installing the SSL certificate in your Azure web role, but **not** the intermediate certificates (i.e. the "certificate chain"). This works for most clients (browsers) because most browsers have the intermediate certificates for major CAs baked into them. In other words, the browsers know how to get from your SSL certificate up to the CA that issued it. But some clients require that the website itself publish not only the SSL certificate but also all of the intermediate certificates.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46900452/1637105) for details on how to do this.

Comment: wish I have read this before. I went through almost same path. some of the [details here](http://youmayneedthis.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/getting-pfx-file-for-nodejs-https-server-from-godaddy-ssl-certificate/) may help someone.

Comment: No button or text field for '3.Tell the wizard to store the key in your Personal store' in IIS Manager 7.5. And there is no button to 'export it a pfx file' in the Actions pane or context menu. Any idea?

Comment: Very good description.  One thing that needs mentioning is that you MUST do "Complete Request" on the same machine as "Create Request".  If you do it on another machine - there is no Export option.

Comment: i could reach down through the internet and kiss you right now. Thank you! Thank you. Great explanation.

Comment: To install IIS: Search for and open "Turn Windows features on or off". Select "Internet Information Services" and click OK.
If it fails with an error such as '0x800F0906' you may need to temporarily disable your antivirus while installing.

Comment: Why can't Azure just make the PFX for me from the CRT - it seems like an unnecessary chore that solves no security issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent many hours on this today and finally got it to work! Putting it out here to save someone from this waste of time. (I don't understand why Azure only accepts pfx and why dns companies do not provide this file to save their customers from this, but here we are, caught in the middle).

My instructions are for GoDaddy and Windows 10.

It should work with other providers, but if you are not on Windows, the last set of instructions won't work as they need a Windows MMC...

### Prerequisites:

1. When creating SSL certificate with your provider, save **private key** into a file (e.g. generated-private-key.txt). If you don't have the private key, this will not work!
2. Download **crt/pem certificates** from provider (from GoDaddy you get three files in a zip: .crt, .pem and .p7b). I think you only really need crt, but at this time I am not changing anything! You can try to omit pem later. There is a way to get these from p7b using openSSL (see the end of instructions), but you are better off getting them from your SSL provider, these are normally supplied, unlike pfx.
3. You will need **openSSL** tool which you can [download for Windows from here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). There's probably other ways to get it, this worked for me in June 2022.

### TL;DR

Use openSSL to convert to pfx. This alone does not work because the cert does not contain exportable private key. So I use certlm mmc to include the key in the second cert.

### Detailed Instructions

**1. Convert your certificate to pfx format using openSSL**

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey generated-private-key.txt -in goDaddy.crt -certfile goDaddy.pem
```

You will be asked to provide a password, do not leave it blank. This cert does not contain private key which is why you need to do it all again with MMC. Maybe there is a way to tell openSSL to do it, but I have no fight left in me at this point.

**2. Start Certificates MMC on Windows (certlm)**

Type `certlm` in Windows command

**3. Import pfx certificate**

In certlm, right-click on personal, and choose import from the menu
[image]

Go through the wizard, making sure you select the pfx file created in step 1. Make sure you select **make key exportable**, include extended properties, and provide the password you specified in step 1. Place the cert in personal.

[image]

**4. Export the certificate to pfx with the private key**

Right click on the personal certificate you imported in step 3, and choose export from the menu. Make sure you select the option to **include the private key**. *This is important.* If this option is not there, it won't work.

[image]

In the next step in the wizard select option as per below image.

[image]

Finally select triple DES encryption and provide the password (can be the same as the one you used in step 1). Did not work for me with AES encryption, but that may change in future. If one encryption does not work, try the other one. At the time of writing DES was working (June 2022).

[image]

**5. Import into Azure**

Go to Azure Portal and import the certificate you exported in step 4 (not the initial one from step 1).

**Optional**
If you did not get crt file from provider, you can extract it from the p7b file with this command:

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in goDaddy.p7b -out certificate.crt
```