# My registrar gave me a .crt and a .pem file for my SSL request - Can't export to PFX, so how can i use it in Azure?

Tags: iis, ssl, azure

I guess the title say it all.

Here's what I did :

1. I used IIS 7 to create a certificate request, it gave me a txt file.
2. I copy / paste the text in my registrar SSL service provider for a particular domain
3. After two email confirm, my SSL request is accepted by my registrar (GANDI.net)
4. I get a download for - a *.crt file and a *.pem file
5. I can install the certificates but just can't import these directly from IIS
6. After installing it shows on crtmgr.exe but I CAN'T EXPORT TO *.pfx file (grayed)
7. Windows Azure need a PFX file

Comment: Which method do you use to install the certificates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The certificate has to be marked as exportable for the cert tool to be able to export it.

You can try if openssl can do it with the [pkcs12](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html) toolset. I don't have an instalation handy to test, but something like the following:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in file.pem -inkey file.crt -passin password -out file.p12
```

There are many Windows ports of OpenSSL, like [OpenSSL for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can use IIS Administrator to create the pfk file.  I wrote up the entire end-to-end procedure in this SO answer:  [convert p7b to pfx for Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708223/convert-p7b-to-pfx-for-azure/14968039#14968039).

Comment: Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)