# I received .crt .pem and .p7b file from GoDaddy to setup SSL. How can I generate a .pfx file from them using openssl

Tags: azure, iis, openssl, azure-web-app-service

[image]

I received .crt .pem and .p7b file from GoDaddy to setup SSL. How can I generate a .pfx file from them using openssl

Comment: One option is to use Namecheap's SSL Converter, a Web UI on top of OpenSSL: https://decoder.link/converter

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708223/convert-p7b-to-pfx-for-azure/72581562#72581562

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are after a [PKCS#12](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-pkcs12.html) file. In this case you should be able to do something like so:

```sh
openssl pkcs12 -export -in your.crt -inkey your.pem -out resulting.pfx
```

options are pretty self-explanatory. Depending on whether your source key is password-protected you might also need to supply that via `-passin/-passout` values

Comment: running in powershell on a windows PC is get openssl is not a recognized as a name of cmdlet, function, [...etc... ]

Comment: i think i ran this in `git bash`. I also know this binary is part of git for Windows package, so adding `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` to PATH may also work